# What is a duplex

Tags: voice, classical-music, j-s-bach

In this article [Surface Topology in Bach Canons, I: The Möbius strip](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fc-2016-10) the author wrote that

> Canon 5 is described by Bach as a *duplex*, *a* 4: there are 4 voices singing two canons in parallel.

Could you please explain for me what is a **duplex**? And what is **a 4**?

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You quoted the definition of *duplex*: "*there are 4 voices singing two canons in parallel.*"

Comment: So a 4 is also defined by 4 voices singing two canons in parallel?

Comment: @Knumber10: No, *a 4* simply means any four-voices piece. It could be instrumental, sung or anything and it definitely does not need to be a canon, let alone two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`duplex`: just as in `duplex apartment` means there are two floors, here it means there are two voices/tracks to sing, probably a deeper one and a higher one.

`a 4`: in French and Italian (and probably latin ?), this is how you would say `with 4 people`. For instance, `to play (a game, music, ...) with 4 people` would translate to `jouer à 4` in French. So it really just means 4 people are singing.

In the end the definition of `duplex a 4` is exactly what you wrote: `there are 4 voices singing two canons in parallel`.

EDIT: 4 people re singing in total if it's `a 4`. Then if it's duplex you just group those people onto different voices.

Comment: In my opinion it is still to undefined, how the grouping is: duplex (canon à 4) which means we have 4 voices per canon and so 8 voices in total, or (duplex canon) à 4 (four voices grouped into two canons).

Comment: duplex a 4 would means there are 4 people singing in total. Which are then grouped onto two voices. Though the grouping is not defined, so it doesn't say it's two and two people, I guess you could still call a canon with 3 and 1 persons singing on each voice a duplex canon a 4

Comment: Accepted for the the given example, difficult to generalize. I want to point out  however, that *4 voices canon* neither means, that someone sings at all, nor that each voice is only performed by one player/singer.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "*duplex, a 4*" is italicized, which leads me to believe it is a phrase from a different language rather than being a pair of separate terms. Looking at other places on that web page, I see there is at least one other case of italicized text in Latin ("*motu recto et contrario*") referring to Bach's descriptions. The phrase "*duplex, a 4*" could be translated from Latin as "double, from 4" or "two-fold, from 4."

When interpreted as "two canons from 4 voices," this properly matches the source text's explanation of "4 voices singing two canons in parallel."

Comment: Translating "a" as "by" would probably make the most sense, given the latter half of the quote.

Comment: even that, what does "from 4" mean? I mean by 4 should be understood from 4 voices right?

Comment: @Knumber10 Two canons sung by four voices.  Two voices for each canon, as per the following sentence at your link.  "Canon simplex à 3 voci" would be one canon with three voices, as another example.  [Here's a visualization of a canon triplex à 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmzDIE3onAk) which should help; you can clearly see three pairs of voices.